# How do I insert a button in the Gmail inbox page in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I want to add a button/link in a Gmail inbox page in Chrome browser, like "Any.do" plugin.

If the user opens Gmail and opens any mail from the inbox, I just put the button or link in that page?

I am new to plugin concepts.

How can I achieve this?

Regards
Sanju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pretty new to chrome extensions and still figuring this all out but basically there are different types of 'extensions' that you can create for chrome.  Sounds like you want to create a gmail 'gadget',

Contextual Gadgets : https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/gs?csw=1

if you follow the tutorials, it seems pretty straight forward.